# Center logo text in wordpress theme(greenchilli)

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

i tried to fix this for couple hours but i dont know what is wrong.
Any ideas how to center "vege dev" logo on http://dev.vegekrzych.pl page ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is about programming questions and your question does not seem to be about programming. You might be better off asking your question on our sister site [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) or on the [WordPress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this:-

```
header #header{
  text-align: center;
}
#header h1#logo{
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: that work great, thank you so much, i was lost wit those nested h1/logo stuff but you find the right thing. Big thanks !!!